# Maximum and Minimum difference (greedy algorithm)

Tags: c++, loops, c++17, greedy

> Problem:
> You are given an array A ,of n elements.You have to remove exactly n/2 elements from an array and add it to another array B
> (intially empty).Find the maximum and minimum values of difference
> between these two arrays.The difference between those two arrays is
> sum(abs(A[i]-B[i]).

The code only works if the size of the array(N) is even.
Can someone provide a solution which works when the size of array is odd as well.

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;     
//This code only works for even number of elements        

int main(){      
    int n;  
    cin>>n;   
    vector<int> a(n);    
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){      
        cin>>a[i];        
    }       
    sort(a.begin(), a.end());       
    long long mn = 0,mx = 0;               
    for(int i=0;i<n/2;i++){    
        mx+=a[i+n/2]-a[i];         
        mn+=a[2*i+1]-a[2*i];        
    }

    cout<<abs(mn)<<" "<<abs(mx)<<" ";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem statement clearly implies that `n` is even, and doesn't make sense for odd `n`. When `n` is odd, there's no way to "remove exactly `n/2` elements", as one obviously can't remove half an element.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I like to split up the work to easily visualize where efficiencies can be made in the algorithm. The following is very similar to your solution, but works fine for both even and odd length vectors. The average runtime is O(nlogn) for sort with space complexity as O(n) for the vectors.

```
// Given two arrays of equal length, returns their "Difference", O(n) runtime
int ArrayDiff(vector<int> A, vector<int> B)
{
    if (A.size() != B.size() || A.size() == 0) return -1;

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
    {
        sum += abs(A[i] - B[i]);
    }
    return sum;
}

// Given a vector arr, find the max and min "Difference"
void PrintMaxAndMin(vector<int> arr)
{
    int n = arr.size();
    if (n <= 0) return;
    vector<int> Amax, Amin, Bmax, Bmin {};

    // for each iteration of removing n/2 elements, we find the max and min of the arrays
    sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());

    for (int i = 0; i < n/2; i++)
    {
        Amax.push_back(arr[i]);
        Bmax.push_back(arr[n-i-1]);

        Amin.push_back(arr[n-i-1]);
        Bmin.push_back(arr[n-i-2]);
    }

    cout << ArrayDiff(Amax, Bmax) << " " << ArrayDiff(Amin, Bmin) << endl;
}

// Run the above functions on a vector of odd and even sizes
int main(){      
    vector<int> arr_even = { 4,3,2,1 };
    cout << "Even Length Vector: ";
    PrintMaxAndMin(arr_even);

    vector<int> arr_odd = { 5,4,3,2,1 };
    cout << "Odd Length Vector: ";
    PrintMaxAndMin(arr_odd);

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the working example: [live example](https://godbolt.org/z/GzbK7rdcn). Hope this helped.

Program output:

```
Program stdout
Even Length Vector: 4 2
Odd Length Vector: 6 2
```

Comment: The code which you have given returns the same output for size odd and even.                      
Testcases:                                                                                                                                  
    vector<int> arr_even = { 4,3,2,1 };

    vector<int> arr_odd = {5,4,3,2,1};                                                                                          
 Output:Even Length Vector: 4 2
            Odd Length Vector: 4 2

Comment: Oops updated for odd length vectors.

Comment: Thanks for the code,but I have another doubt.The question says that the array needs to be divided in half exactly,so how can you calculate for odd number of elements?

Comment: If the input vector is odd and the vector is sorted, I used the indicies to split the vector in half exactly based on what would yield a greater max and a lesser min. I.E. if arr = { 1, 2, 3 } and I want to find ABmin. Then Amin=1,Bmin=3 is worse than Amin=2,Bmin=3. Not sure if that confused you more.

Comment: Ya it really did confused me,can you can explain it more clearly?